# How do divide txt file numbers into a positive number txt file and negative number txt file

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int masivs[24], x = 0, y = 0;
    int negativi[20];
    int pozitivi[20];
    ifstream f;
    f.open("f.txt");
    while (f.good() && x < 24)
        f >> masivs[x++];
    f.close();
    cout << masivs[1];
    ofstream f2("f2.txt");
    ofstream f1("f1.txt");

    for (x = 0; x < 24; x++)
        if (masivs[x] >= 0)
            pozitivi[x] = masivs[x];
        else
            negativi[x] = masivs[x];

    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        f2 << negativi << endl;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++)
    {
        f1 << pozitivi << endl;
    }
}
```

Ive been trying to find out how to do this for 2 days and im going crazy. Just please tell me how to do it. Im trying to divide the f.txt file numbers into f1.txt with the positives and f2.txt with the negatives. I have to read the f file with an array adn then write the positives in f1 and negatives in f2. and all the zeros in f3. Pls help ive been trying to find info on this but i cant do it.

the f.txt numbers:

```
-9
-8
-7
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Comment: There is *zero* need to an intermediate arrays to solve this problem. You need three files (the source, the positive, and the negative), and the ability to read one value at a time from source, stuffing it into the proper output file dependent on whether the value is negative or not. All the array work, indexing, etc., is pointless and just a feeding ground for bugs (of which there are many).

Comment: Echoing what @WhozCraig said, you'd be better off splitting the separation-of-numbers from the file in/out tasks. Then, each task can be tested separately. Breaking a complex task up into simpler parts - and testing them individually - is the key to developing larger programs

Answer (score 1):

You have two major problems. One benign and one which leads to *undefined behavior*.

The benign problem is the statement

```
f2<<negativi<<endl;
```

This is exactly the same as

```
f2 << &negativi[0] << endl;
```

In other words, it writes a pointer to the first element of `negativi`.

---

The more serious problem is a buffer overflow in the loop

```
for (x = 0; x < 24; x++)
    if (masivs[x] >= 0)
        pozitivi[x] = masivs[x];
    else
        negativi[x] = masivs[x];
```

Here you use the same index `x` for both `pozitivi`, `negativi` *and* `masivs`. This index is only valid for `masivs`.

The loop as it works now with a single index `x` will not only put holes in the `pozitivi` and `negativi` arrays, but also go out of bounds of both.

The solution is to add another index, one each for the `pozitivi` and `negativi` arrays:

```
unsigned p = 0;  // Index for positive number array
unsigned n = 0;  // Index for negative number array

for (unsigned x = 0; x < 24; x++)
{
    if (masivs[x] >= 0)
        pozitivi[p++] = masivs[x];
    else
        negativi[n++] = masivs[x];
}
```

Afterwards you can use `p` and `n` as sizes for the corresponding array, to use when you write the result to the files.

---

And as mentioned in a comment to the question, the arrays aren't really needed which makes much of the code moot, and the whole program *much* simpler. And simplicity is better, as there's less chance of errors.

Comment: Note that since `n` and `p` are both declared local to the for-loop, their usefulness is of no ultimate value beyond that control structure. Afterward you have no idea how many negative vs positive values were read since `n` and `p` are gone. Assuming we keep these unnecessary arrays, `n` and `p` should be moved out of (and before) this loop for access beyond this for-loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple while(getline()) loop...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  int lineNumber, it = 0;
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream f("f.txt");
  std::ofstream f1, f2;
  f1.open("f1.txt");
  f2.open("f2.txt");
  while(std::getline(f, line)) //reads each line of f.txt ino a string
  {
    try
    {
      lineNumber = std::stoi(line);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument& e) //if value is not a number
    {
      std::cout << "VALUE IS NOT A NUMBER ON ITERATION " << it << '\n';
      //std::abort();
      continue;
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range& e) //if value is above +-2^32 +-1
    {
      std::cout << "VALUE OUT OF RANGE ON ITERATION " << it << '\n';
      //std::abort();
      continue;
    }
    if(lineNumber > 0)
    {
      f1 << lineNumber << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
      f2 << lineNumber << '\n';
    }
    it++;
  }
  f1.close();
  f2.close();
}
```

This will get your desired output, file f1.txt containing all the positive numbers, and file f2.txt containing all the negative numbers.

Comment: Why `getline`? Why not `f >> value`? Chances are, if there's non-numeric values in the file the program should exit anyway. Not to mention that you don't really verify that the string really is a number, and will write non-numeric data as negative numbers.

Comment: The file in question only contains numbers. If he is concerned with the values being non-numeric he can add a check. I assumed adding more overhead would just make it more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: Thank you! Im a big newbie so this is really helpful!

Comment: @Ray8r People on here are ruthless, make sure to do your research and think about your issue before posting it on here. It will help you become a better problem solver :)